# Ray of light behind the skyline to the sky, html5, css3 (animation maybe)

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, html5-canvas

Would like to ask if this is possible with HTML (not flash), have a picture lets say some HD picture and create a ray of like just like in the Batman movie that would go from the left to right diagonally to the sky and show circle image on the sky. It will be fullscreen image fade in then ray of light fade in and then circle on the sky. Then entire picture would fade out to other picture which would be just a picture not any other ray of lights or anything. I am not sure if this is possible with HTML5 and CSS3 that would be also resposive - that is optional, most importantly if this can work in browser on mac or pc.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible :) Could you please with us what you tried so far and the code where you got stuck.

Comment: I dont have any code, I am trying to think of if it is even possible, I would like to work with somebody to make it work, but not sure what is the best approach and also mantain responsivness, cause when you resize all elements are moving...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually possible.

Make a 'sandwich' animation with **two layers**. 
One is the **background** and the other one is the **light beam**. The beam animation can be animated both with javascript or css3. I suggest to use css3, since it is very fast and use graphic acceleration.

To make it responsive, you could implement the animation on **two divs**, the **#beam** and the **#background**, the first one overlaying the second one. The images will be set as **background-size: cover**.

To make it responsive right and always have the batman logo on the center of the screen, simply add **background-position-x: 100%;** to both #beam and #background.

To make it nice to look on mobile I would suggest to use **different size images** which you can manage with **media queries** in css3. Also, I would use PNGs with progressive mode enabled (you can enable it simply saving in photoshop as PNG progressive). This way the image will be a layer of three images in three resolution, slightly heavier, but the browser will show at first the lower resolution picture while still downloading the full picture, and then when completed automagically switch to HD image.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it can be done.

The animations are bascially done using javascript.
If needed you can use [kinetic.js](http://kineticjs.com/) or [fabric.js](http://kineticjs.com/) to help you out with your project.
Even CSS3 animations can be done using sprite images and so on. :)